# Regex syntax for counting occurance of a pattern match

Tags: c#, regex, office365, predicate

I am currently implementing Built in Data Loss Prevention (DLP) feature in Microsoft Exchange on Cloud, Office 365. I need to create a pattern lets say "X12345789" which is sensitive to the organization to check on mail attachments going outside the organization. Now I have tested using `X\d{9}` and it works fine. However, my requirement is to match this pattern occurrence more than 20 in a particular file.

For e.g: If the file contains below information,

```
X123456789
X234561285
X873674335
X555234922
X112233445
```

..and so on till the count is more than 20, then only take action.

Can a regular expression be created based on this requirement?

Currently I am getting responses on every single pattern match. I am interested only in Bulk Information passing in a transaction.

Also the regex should ignore other text data with spaces or commas that are used in excel.
For eg: 
It should also detect even when the format is as below

X123456789 ergei slova  6284201245  HR,TA

Comment: If you don't necessarily need the Matches, you could just encompass your Regex search pattern in yet another group. Something like `Regex.IsMatch(input, "(X\d{9}){20}")` would work if they're all consecutive. If they're not necessarily consecutive, you could do something like `Regex.IsMatch(input, "(X\d{9}[^(X\d{9})]*){20}")`

Comment: @Meloviz the second one did the trick.Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: It look like the given solution is partially working.If I put a file as "X584278522        abc Xyz 9871114717         ADCPA2029G     abcxyz@yahoo.com" with more than 20 rows in a body of email or in an spreadsheet attachment, the pattern match fails. Can anyone help here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your regular expression all configured and set up using the `Regex` class, this should be pretty straightforward.

```
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(myString); // assumes regex is Regex regex = Regex(pattern)
// OR
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(myString, myPattern);
if(matches.Count > 20)
{
    /* Do something */
}
```

This will basically check your input, and put all the matches in to a `MatchCollection` object where it can be used to do whatever you need to do with the matched tokens.